# Free software for measuring parts of an image?

Tags: software, measurement

Let's say I have a picture of an insect wing and a ruler on the same image. Is there any computer program that I can use to calibrate with the ruler and then get a measurement on the wing length? Would the software be able to export these data to a spreadsheet?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about software not Biology.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/) is all you need. Particularly see the documentation sections on [setting the image scale](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-30.html#sub%3aSet-Scale...) and [measuring](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-30.html#toc-Subsection-30.1).

Comment: This is great! Thanks! It even continues to add values from new images into the table. Awesome!

Comment: see also [Fiji](http://fiji.sc/Fiji) for a distribution of ImageJ with more plug-ins

Answer (score 1):

[WebPlotDigitizer](http://arohatgi.info/WebPlotDigitizer) is an online application that can also be used to make distance and angle measurements in an image.

Comment: Looks interesting. I will try it at the next chance.